# Is there a way to make iSpy use more GPU instead of CPU?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, graphics-card, gpu, ip-camera

I have a server PC that I use for camera surveillance sytem with iSpy. There are 5 cameras, and the average fps is pretty low. I checked it with Process Manager, and it seems that iSpy only uses the CPU, and the GPU load is <1%, even though the PC has a video card (GT 730). The cameras are IC-3115W, so their video feed is M-JPEG.

Is there a way to make iSpy use more GPU to process the video? Based on the output files, iSpy encodes the MJPEG signal into H264, is there a way to assign that work to the GPU? Maybe an nVidia/ffmpeg setting?

I tried setting "FFMPEG (H264)" as video source, as there is a `Use GPU` option, however it makes no difference. There is an `encoder` setting, too (`software/nvidia/quicksync/amd`), but none of the options make any difference in terms of GPU usage.

Comment: `Use GPU` would indeed be hardware acceleration for the encoder.  You should tried that option and update your question with all relevant information required to answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the reply, I spent the day experimenting, added the notes.

Comment: There are h/w encoders for h264 with ffmpeg: `h264_amf`, `h264_nvenc` and `h264_qsv` have you tried those?

Comment: @cyberquarks Are those options somewhere in iSpy's settings?